# Why is ViewContext.DisplayMode.DisplayModeId empty?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mobile-website

I'm using custom DisplayModes for ASP.NET MVC 4 (RC) views to allow customization of view content.

My rules for this mobile only app are very simple and defined based on a user's internal profile/session configuration:

```
DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0,
    new DefaultDisplayMode("Tablet")
    {
        ContextCondition = (context =>
        {
            if (SessionManager.Current == null)
                return false;   // assume phone initially

            if (SessionManager.Current.Session.ScreenWidth > 600)
                return true;

            return false;
        })
    });

DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0,
    new DefaultDisplayMode("Phone")
    {
        ContextCondition = (context =>
        {                        
            if (SessionManager.Current == null ||
                SessionManager.Current.Session.ScreenWidth <= 600)
                return true;   // assume phone initially

            return false;
        })
    });
```

I can now create views that use xxxx.Phone.cshtml and xxxx.Tablet.cshtml. The right views are rendered.

However, ViewContext.DisplayMode.DisplayModeId always comes back blank. For example, in the following page I echo back the display mode and a hardcoded id to tell which view was rendered:

```
<div>@Model.Distance - @ViewContext.DisplayMode.DisplayModeId  - Tablet</div>
```

I see the hardcoded Tablet (or Phone) value, but the DisplayModeId is always blank.

Should this value be set? I think this worked in previous builds of MVC 4 beta, but I'm not 100% sure.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When I  remember correctly, this could happen when ContextCondition is set to null.
When that happens all the other DisplayModeProvider aren't considered.

Are you sure that none of the ContextCondition return null? Perhaps because of an exception inside the delegate? Have you tried to return fixed values (for testing purpose?

Comment: Did some more testing. Couldn't confirm it with the latest MVC4 version. Did work like expected. What I can confirm is, that the first DisplayMode with ContextCondition=null is returned. Independend from the others.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the mode with `ViewContext.DisplayMode.DisplayModeId` is not practical. The code works only if your view is named ViewName.Table.cshtml. If only your master is _Master.Tablet.cshtml, the property will return empty result.

So pretty much you will get the correct result only if your view is the correct mode, which makes getting the mode pointless.